# Write (large amount of) zeros into a binary file

Tags: python, file, binary

This might be a stupid question but I'm unable to find a proper answer to it. I want to store (don't ask why) a binary representation of a `(2000, 2000, 2000)` array of zeros into disk, binary format. The traditional approach to achieve so would be:

```
with open('myfile', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('\0' * 4 * 2000 * 2000 * 2000)  # 4 bytes = float32
```

But that would imply creating a very large string which is not necessary at all. I know of two other options:

- Iterate over the elements and store one byte at a time (extremely slow)
- Create a numpy array and flush it to disk (as memory expensive as the string creation in the example above)

I was hopping to find something like `write(char, ntimes)` (as it exists in C and other languages) to copy on disk `char` `ntimes` at C speed, and not at Python-loops speed, without having to create such a big array on memory.

Comment: Why not create a string of some reasonable size, like 100k or so, then write it out multiple times in a loop?

Comment: That would be an option, but I don't know the shape of the array in advance (2000^3 is an example), and calculating a *reasonable size* and looping at python speed would still be slower. It is not a bad solution (and maybe is the only one), but I was hoping that someone would come up with a library/method/something I'm missing that  allows to do that without having to loop (e.g. a Cython extension).

Comment: If the array is dense (packed), then the shape shouldn't matter, only the total number of bytes, right?  Look at it this way:  The result should be indistinguishable from your example of doing a single write of one enormous string.

Comment: if you are on a unix based system you can just use [`dd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275243/what-does-dd-if-dev-zero-of-dev-sda-do) and get your zeros from `/dev/zero`

Comment: @TomKarzes You are right. And probably is the best solution so far.

Comment: It's the same thing that would happen if you were to copy an existing file:  The source file is read in chunks, and those chunks are written out.  The only difference is you're generating a single chunk from within your program, then writing that same chunk multiple times.

Comment: @Nullman that sounds quite interesting solution, but I would need it as a python function in a multi-platform environment.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, but usually the chunking and looping is done at C speed, not in Python.

Comment: I'm not sure how portable this is: `f.seek(4*2000*2000*2000-1)`, then write a single null byte and close the file. It depends on the underlying I/O library zeroing out any blocks not explicitly written.

Comment: @chepner will try that one :O

Comment: No, it's done at file I/O speed, which will be slower than either C or Python.  Honestly, you seem to be inventing problems that don't exist.

Comment: @chepner I see little advantage to making it system-dependent like that, and implementing a solution that *only* works if you're writing all 0s (as opposed to all 1s for instance).  Yes, most operating systems will clear the storage so you don't end up with the contents of some previous file, but I honestly think OP is just inventing artificial problems.  This question is really becoming a waste of time.  The solution is painfully obvious, but OP doesn't want to use it.

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm looking to chunking to asses the performance of it. You could provide an answer that supports your claims instead of blaming me for wanting to test it.

Comment: what about using a sparse matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are making such a fuss about "Python's loop speed", but writing in the way of

```
for i in range(2000 * 2000):
     f.write('\0' * 4 * 2000)  # 4 bytes = float32
```

will tell the OS to write 8000 0-bytes. After `write` returns, in the next loop run it is called again.

It might be that the loop is executed slightly slower than it would be in C, but that definitely won't make a difference.

If it is ok to have a sparse file, you as well can seek to the desired file size's position and then truncate the file.

Comment: Is not that I don't like python loops, is more like I was hoping to see other alternatives, and hopefully, a lower level API to this. Apparently, the standard `write(byte, length)` is not available in python, and this would be the next best thing. I would take out of the loop `data = '\0' * 4 * 2000` to avoid iterative creation of that array, but that is also secondary.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo `f.write(s)` is exactly the standard `write(bytes, length)`: the length is encoded in the string. And if you have a string of which you want to write a part of, you can use a `buffer()` object: `write(buffer(longstring, 10000, 12))` as an alternative to slicing.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a valid answer to fill a file from Python using [numpy's memmap:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)

```
shape = (2000, 2000, 2000) # or just (2000 * 2000 * 2000,)
fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=shape)
fp[...] = 0
```

Comment: Is this faster than @glglgl's answer?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Probably not, but his answer was first.

Answer (score 1):

To write zeroes, there's a nice hack: open the file in read-write, seek to the offset minus one, and write another zero.

This pads the start of the file with zeroes as well:

```
mega_size = 100000
with open("zeros.bin","wb+") as f:
    f.seek(mega_size-1)
    f.write(bytearray(1))
```

Answer (score -1):

The original poster does not make clear why this really needs to be done in python. So here is a little shell script command which does the same thing, but probably slightly faster. Assuming the OP is on a unix like system (linux / Mac)

Definitions: bs (blocksize) = 2000 * 2000, count = 4 * 2000
The if (input file) is a special 'zero producing' device. The of (output file) has to be specified as wel.

```
dd bs=4000000 count=8000  if=/dev/zero of=/Users/me/thirtygig
```

On my computer (ssd) this takes about 110 seconds:
*32000000000 bytes transferred in 108.435354 secs (295106705 bytes/sec)*

You can always call this little shell command from python.

For comparisons, @glglgl little python script runs in 303 seconds on the same computer, so only 3 times slower, which is probably fast enough.